# Unable to render a react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to create below React component but it's not getting rendered.

**script.jsx**

```
var Button = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: () => {
        return {
          counter: 0
        };
      },
      handleClick: () => {
        this.setState({
          counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
      },
      render: () => {
        return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}> this.state.counter </button>);
        }
      });

    React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>React App</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="libs/react-15.0.2.js"></script>
    <script src="script.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

can anyone please let me know whats going wrong here.

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit more.  What error are you experiencing?

Comment: Is `script.js` in the `<script>` supposed to be `script.jsx`?

Comment: @DavinTryon the react Button component is not getting rendered on the browser.

Comment: @Dinu If you check the developer console in your browser do you see any error messages?

Comment: @DavinTryon I tried changing the script ref to script.jsx but no luck

Comment: If you are trying to import the script without compiling it first the browser will not know how to handle the JSX syntax. Can you check your developer console for any error messages?

Comment: @Brayniverse I see an error in the console saying 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
at line `<button onClick={this.handleClick}> this.state.counter </button>` in render function.

Comment: I think I know the problem then, give me a minute and I'll find you a link explaining how to compile the JSX syntax to normal JavaScript. For your reference, this is what the compiled JavaScript looks like. [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z356qjwp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple small things you need to do before your code will run there.

Firstly you need to compile JSX to normal JS. Browsers do not know how to interpret JSX and thus will throw an exception `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <...`. To compile your JSX you can use a tool called [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/). They have a few examples of how to compile JSX to JS on [their blog](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/02/23/babel-loves-react), or you can try following one of these tutorials.

- [Setting Up a React.js Environment Using Npm, Babel 6 and Webpack](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack)
- [Setting up React for ES6 with Webpack and Babel](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)

The second thing I noticed is that you are calling `React.render(...)`. This method has been deprecated for a couple versions of ReactJS. You need to import a different library called [ReactDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) to render the component in the browser.

Here is an example of the code that should work after you have compiled it.

```js
'use strict';

var Button = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Button',

  getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    };
  },
  handleClick: function handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },
  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'button',
      { onClick: this.handleClick },
      this.state.counter
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Button, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<h1>React App</h1>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you need any more information add a comment below and I will update this answer.

Comment: thanks for the info, lot of things to configure the react environment. Will follow the links provided and revert.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the example you're following is a bit outdated? There are several issues in the code. First of all, you should now use

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then, in order to load JSX code in your browser, you need to run it through Babel. And even if you do that, this might not work:

> Note that some browsers (Chrome, e.g.) will fail to load the file unless it's served via HTTP.

(from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

So you might be much better off using something like webpack or browserify.

In your render function, you should enclose the reference to the counter in curly braces because it is JavaScript:

```
{ this.state.counter }
```

And last not least, if you're starting out learning React, I'd suggest you start with using plain JavaScript classes because this seems to be the way to go for React:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0};
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button
          onClick={ () => this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1}) }>
          {this.state.counter}
          </button>
    );
  }
}
```